# DNS delegation of the subdomain and the sub-subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have a question about delegation of a subdomain and a sub-subdomain from the same server.

I have a DNS server `NS1` where I have a delegation for the domain `dom2.example.com` pointed to the server `NS2`. I.e. on the server `NS1` I have a record like:

```
dom2.example.com NS NS2
```

And on the server `NS2` I have a delegation for the domain `dom3.dom2.example.com` pointed to the server `NS3`. I.e. on the server `NS1` I have a record like:

```
dom3.dom2.example.com NS NS3
```

I would like to move that last NS record to the server `NS1`. What will then happen if the client makes a DNS query for the record `record1.dom3.dom2.example.com`

Will the server `NS1` forward to the server `NS2` or to the server `NS3`?

I.e. will the delegation of the sub-subdomain work if the subdomain itself is delegated?

Thanks.

Comment: "And on the server NS2 I have a delegation ... I.e. on the server NS1 I have a record like:" this is not clear or contradictory. Is the delegation out of NS2 or NS1? Also, it may be simpler just to give the real names when discussing things...

Comment: Also please do not say "forward".  This term does not exist in the DNS, it comes from HTTP land. DNS does not "forward" queries from one zone to another in the sense you use it. DNS uses delegations and zone cuts, to find out authoritative nameservers for a given name.